# Nginx: alias and try_files with $args

Tags: nginx, php

When I try to use `try_files` with `?$args` at `location /api/v1` I get error 404. Without it it's working properly. Any idea?

---

Nginx Configuration

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name domain.com;

    index index.php;
    root  /home/ec2-user/dev.domain.com.br/webroot/default/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /api/v1 {
        alias /home/ec2-user/dev.domain.com/webroot/apiv1/web;

        # Works, but don't parse args.
        try_files $uri /api/v1/index.php; ## << WORKING

        # Do not work. Error 404.
        try_files $uri /api/v1/index.php?$args; ## << ERROR

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            include         fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: this is a huge find, please share it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are issues](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) when you use `try_files` and `alias` directives together.

As a work around, remove `alias` and use `root` and `rewrite`.